# OpenCV error on Raspberry Pi in fuction cvtColor

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am using a Raspberry Pi Model B+ with a fresh install of Raspbian and a raspberry pi camera. I was playing around with some OpenCV code especially for object tracking. I found a certain piece of code and it worked initially.

Here is the code in question.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):

# Take each frame
_, frame = cap.read()

# Convert BGR to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# define range of blue color in HSV
lower_blue = np.array([110, 50, 50], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255], dtype=np.uint8)

# Threshold the HSV image to get only blue colors
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)

# Bitwise-AND mask and original image
res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)

cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
cv2.imshow('res',res)
k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
if k == 27:
    break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But when I tried to run it again, I ran into this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/Alpha/object.py", line 50, in <module>
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
error: /usr/src/packages/BUILD/opencv-2.4.1+dfsg/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3344: error: (-215) (scn == 3 || scn == 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) in function cvtColor
```

Any help please? It worked the first time around but afterwards it just doesn't work. I've tried just about everything.

Comment: Shouldn't you have something in the body of `while`?

Comment: please test whether the image is empty after `.read` (in that case, close program or just skip that loop iteration) probably your camera wasnt "closed" properly and your program isnt allowed to access it again. Try to unplug the camera

Comment: Regarding the while, there is something under there. I guess when I copied and pasted it here, it formatted the code differently.

Comment: You're not releasing capture at the end of your code. The solution you provided is not correct answer even though it solved your problem temporarily. As Micka said, you need to check if frame is empty after each read operation and continue with later code if frame is not empty. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

So I found an answer. All I had to do was run this code on my raspberry pi:

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

Thank you for all the help.